# How to Decrypt Clock Time values into Text using Clock Cipher?

Tags: python, math, encryption, clock, puzzle

I have been trying to decode and crack some clock times I have been received into there related letters to get the meaning in (text) , I Researched and I used **(clock cipher )** online encrypter but I couldn't understand very well It generates multiple results for a specific time input .

I also saw a representation of clock time with letters online as I Uploaded in below and I tried to solve it manually :

Clock face cipher:
[image]

and these are the following times I have :

[
8:00pm
7:50pm
11:01pm
11:25pm

5:00pm

8:28pm
9:45pm
11:25pm
12:15am
12:35am
11:15am
7:05pm
11:15pm
2:35pm
10:35pm
5:55pm
8:45pm

~pm

8:15pm
10:40pm
10:45pm
8:05pm
8:30pm
8:40pm
11:11pm
11:11pm
12:20pm
12:41pm
1:15am
9:15pm
11:22pm

12:45am
1:25am

]

Can anyone help me to decode theses messages into their real meaning ?

are there any other method to solve the problem with ?

Comment: To be clear: the image included in your post was not given to you by the same person who gave you the puzzle, it is just an image that you found at random when searching for "clock cipher" with Google?

Comment: Perhaps https://puzzling.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask that question.

Comment: @Stef exactly as that I Found it my self on the internet that's why i can't find the right method